# Is there a good reference guide for deciphering http user-agent strings?

Tags: http, user-agent

We're getting some odd errors reported on our website, and are trying to find out some details on who is doing the looking.  I'm looking at a sample user-agent strings and seeing things like:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6

Now some of this is obvious, but some of it is less so ("U"?)  From the pattern of the hits, I'd suspect that this was a robot, but I don't see anything that I recognize in this string to clue me in to that.  I'd like to know what some of the things in this (and other different) strings mean.  Is there a comprehensive reference somewhere?

Comment: The [history](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/) is [interesting](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) gives a good overview, and describes the meaning of the 'U' attribute as well.

Answer (score 2):

User-agent strings (as all request headers) are not to be trusted at all, but I recommend [**www.useragentstring.com**](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) as a reference for helping you determine the patterns you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks.  How many people know what your name means, btw?  On a geek site like this I would guess a higher percentage than elsewhere, but I'd bet it's still somewhat low...

Answer (score 2):

The U stands for security as the [Mozilla User Agent String Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/User_Agent_Strings_Reference) states. The link to wikipedia has been provided by somebody else already

In future I suggest you use these two sites

http://www.useragentstring.com/

http://www.browserscope.org/

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060214 Firefox/3.0.11

This is my current user agent.
Mozilla/5.0 - browser
Macintosh - platform
U - 256 bit encryption supported
Intel Mac OS X 10.5 - my operating system
en-US - language
rv:1.9.0.11 - revision
Gecko/2009060214 - rendering engine
Firefox/3.0.11 - browser version

Answer (score 0):

Robots can fake User-Agent strings, so what it declares is irrelevant. It can simply be done with e.g. `curl -A user-agent-here`.

Comment: Oh yes, I know that...but it seems like that because of the bad press that surrounds that kind of thing, they usually don't bother (unless they have some kind of potentially nefarious purpose).